# Opening the older solution with visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, ide, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to switch from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022Codes runs fine but shows CS0103 The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context in Visual Studio 2022
Code gets executed and runs fine. The same code is totally fine in visual studio 2019 without any errors
[image: this is file.aspx]
[image: this is file.aspx.cs Ids from file.aspx file is shown not found in file.aspx.cs file in visual studio 2022]

Comment: try clearing the cache, or rebuild the project

Comment: From the dropdown check "Build only" instead of Build + Intellisense.

Comment: After an initial build with the new version (particularly if you have updated the runtime version as well), you might need to close and reopen VS to properly sync the caches.

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers. Did you check the comments above?